# jquery cookies in edge animate

Tags: jquery, cookies, jquery-animate, jquery-cookie, adobe-edge

So in a regular html5 page in IE I can get the following jquery code to work:

```
       $.cookie('mycookieX',cookieXcounter,{expires:7,path:'/'});

       $.cookie('mycookieY',cookieYcounter,{expires:7,path:'/'});



       console.log($.cookie('mycookieX'));
```

But I can't get the code to work in my edgeActions.js file... I tried changing up the syntax (since when I use jquery in edge before I've had to change things for example:

```
       $('#blueCar').animate({

        left:carArrayX[carArrayXcounter] + "px",

        top:carArrayY[carArrayYcounter] + "px"

        }); '
```

to

```
       sym.$('blueCar').animate({

       left:myVariableX + "px",

       top:myVariableY + "px" 

       });
```

but I can't figure out the cookies in edge with jquery to get them workign... It's probaby a syntax thing but all I could think of was this:

```
      sym. $.cookie('mycookieX',cookieXcounter,{expires:7,path:'/'});

      sym. $.cookie('mycookieY',cookieYcounter,{expires:7,path:'/'});



       console.log($.cookie('mycookieX'));
```

--------------------------> and of course this doesn't work..

Please provide thoughts...

Comment: oh yeah, this is the jquery-cookies plugin I'm using: jquery.cookie.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never was able to get the plugin for jquery-cookies.js to work with edge animate, which should have been the simplest to cache:

```
//jquery cookies not working in edge animate:
                                        //  $.cookie('mycookieX',btnArrayX,{expires:7,path:'/'});                                       
                                         // $.cookie('mycookieY',btnArrayY,{expires:7,path:'/'});
                                         //console.log($.cookie('mycookieX'));
```

but I did get javascript (taken from another user on stackoverflow) to work with edge animate:

```
//set cookie
                                            function createCookie(name,value,days) {
                                                if (days) {
                                                    var date = new Date();
                                                    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
                                                    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
                                                }
                                                else var expires = "";
                                                document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
                                            }

                                            createCookie('ppkcookie',btnArrayX,7);

//read cookie

                                                function readCookie(name) {
                                                    var nameEQ = name + "=";
                                                    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
                                                    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
                                                        var c = ca[i];
                                                        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
                                                        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
                                                    }
                                                    return null;
                                                }

                                            var yayCookie = readCookie('ppkcookie');
                                            console.log('yayCookie' + yayCookie);
```

So, I guess anyone trying to read/set cookie in edge animate... it's probably still possible with the jquery plugin, I just don't know the correct syntax to make it edge animate compatible.. but the good news it that straight javascript (although longer) works fine :)